# Adding a column in Pandas with a function

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
  columnA  columnB
0   10        90
1   83        17
2   30        21
...
```

and I have a function like this:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    value = #do some calculation
    return value
```

Now I want to get a new column `columnC` for my dataframe based on the calculations of the function.
Obviously, `df["columnC"]= my_func(df["columnA"], df["columnB"])` does not work.

What can I do to add the column?

Comment: use pandas ``apply`` : ``df['C'] = df.apply(my_func)``

Comment: This also passes a pandas-series to my function. It is the same problem with the example I gave above.

Comment: Can you post what `my_func` does?

Comment: It's just some big if/return block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do it is:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. It's a bit  hacky though...

```
df["columnC"]=pd.Series([my_func(row["columnA"], row["columnB"])for index, row in df.iterrows()], index=df.index)
```