# Looking for lookup code to add columns to Pandas dataframe queried from same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add columns to a dataframe based on another row of the same dataframe.  I would like to look up the row with the first column value equal to the value in column 5 and append columns 2, 3, and 4 to the dataframe as below

```
1  2  3  4  5
a  b  c  d  i
e  f  g  h  i
i  j  k  l  e

1  2  3  4  5  2a 3a 4a
a  b  c  d  i  j  k  l
e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
i  j  k  l  e  f  g  h
```

I have tried creating another table to merge `df2 = df.loc[(df.1 == df.5)` in various combinations but no luck.

Comment: Do any of the links here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182958/adding-a-column-in-pandas-with-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That was a good place to start.  In the process I realized though that i could just merge it with itself

Answer (score 0):

Decided to merge the dataframe with itself:

```py
dfleft = df.merge(df,how='left', left_on='5', right_on='1')
```

just need to rename columns after that